# Insertar múltiples datos con valores definidos y de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola estoy un poco perdido para poder insertar múltiples datos con datos desde otra tabla

actualmente envió desde el front múltiples datos para insertar con la siguiente query

```
INSERT INTO order (nombre, sku, precio) VALUES (('PVC 12x12', '011', '650'), ('PVC 16x16', '012', '700'))
```

hasta allí todo bien inserto múltiples datos

pero necesito también almacenar en otras columnas de la table "order" varios valores que se encuentra en la tabla "products".

Mi tabla products contiene (ID, nombre, sku, precio, almacenado, puesto)

para mi tabla "order" necesito completar las columnas donde esta almacenado y el puesto donde esta el producto según el SKU por cada inserción.

Answer (score 0):

Lo recomendable en tu caso sería almacenar únicamente el `ID` del producto, meter valores duplicados en una tabla no es una buena práctica a menos que sea estrictamente necesario. así que lo mejor que puedes hacer es lo que te digo.

Y cuando necesites los valores de la tabla productos basta con hacer un `inner join` entre `order` y `products`.

Comment: entiendo pero para este caso es necesario guardar esos datos también en la orden para tener un historial de donde salieron los productos ya que luego el producto lo pueden cambiar de lugar o mover de donde lo tienen almacenado